# not in clause of same table takes time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

the query is like..

```
select deviceid,devicename,totalbytes,'Others' as protocolgroup from (
    select d.deviceid,d.name as devicename,sum(bytes) as totalbytes from tblmainallowedtraffic_5min  b,tbldevice d
    WHERE (  B.APPID IN ('C070100126-VW717U','C018600068-GEF3O6','C045701665-9B6S1A','C026100710-36NPQE','C016801597-V1Z8IM') ) 
    and proto_group not in (select proto_group from (select proto_group,sum(bytes) from
    TBLMAINALLOWEDTRAFFIC_5MIN B WHERE (  B.APPID IN ('C070100126-VW717U','C018600068-GEF3O6','C045701665-9B6S1A',
    'C026100710-36NPQE','C016801597-V1Z8IM') ) AND "5mintime" >='04-APR-12 12.00.00.000000 AM' AND
    "5mintime" <='04-APR-12 11.59.59.000000 PM' group by proto_group order by sum(bytes) desc ) WHERE ROWNUM <=5 )
    AND B.APPID=D.APPID AND "5mintime" >='04-APR-12 12.00.00.000000 AM' AND "5mintime" <='04-APR-12 11.59.59.000000 PM' 
    GROUP BY D.APPID,D.DEVICEID,D.NAME)
    order by protocolgroup desc, totalbytes desc
```

in Explain plan it says that..

3 - filter( NOT EXISTS (not feasible))

If i change the above query with static inner query result,the output comes faster:

```
 select deviceid,devicename,totalbytes,'Others' as protocolgroup from (
    select d.deviceid,d.name as devicename,sum(bytes) as totalbytes from tblmainallowedtraffic_5min  b,tbldevice d
    WHERE (  B.APPID IN ('C070100126-VW717U','C018600068-GEF3O6','C045701665-9B6S1A','C026100710-36NPQE','C016801597-V1Z8IM') ) 
    and proto_group not in ('POP3','HTTP Request Response','Web','GET HTTP DATA MORE THAN 976 KB','SMTP' )
    AND B.APPID=D.APPID AND "5mintime" >='04-APR-12 12.00.00.000000 AM' AND "5mintime" <='04-APR-12 11.59.59.000000 PM' 
    GROUP BY D.APPID,D.DEVICEID,D.NAME)
    order by protocolgroup desc, totalbytes desc
```

so not exists clause is aplied on same table creates the problem..
can you give some idea on this,,?

Comment: You might use [Instant sql formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) online tool to format sql.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** New answer:

Try doing an anti-join:

```
SELECT deviceid,
  devicename,
  totalbytes,
  'Others' AS protocolgroup
FROM
  (SELECT d.deviceid,
    d.name     AS devicename,
    SUM(bytes) AS totalbytes
  FROM tblmainallowedtraffic_5min b,
    tbldevice d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT proto_group
    FROM
      (SELECT proto_group,
        SUM(bytes)
       FROM TBLMAINALLOWEDTRAFFIC_5MIN B
       WHERE ( B.APPID IN ('C070100126-VW717U','C018600068-GEF3O6','C045701665-9B6S1A', 'C026100710-36NPQE','C016801597-V1Z8IM') )
         AND "5mintime"  >='04-APR-12 12.00.00.000000 AM'
         AND "5mintime"  <='04-APR-12 11.59.59.000000 PM'
       GROUP BY proto_group
       ORDER BY SUM(bytes) DESC
      )
    WHERE ROWNUM <=5
    ) e ON b.proto_group = e.proto_group
  WHERE ( B.APPID     IN ('C070100126-VW717U','C018600068-GEF3O6','C045701665-9B6S1A','C026100710-36NPQE','C016801597-V1Z8IM') )
  AND e.proto_group is null
  AND B.APPID     =D.APPID
  AND "5mintime" >='04-APR-12 12.00.00.000000 AM'
  AND "5mintime" <='04-APR-12 11.59.59.000000 PM'
  GROUP BY D.APPID,
    D.DEVICEID,
    D.NAME
  )
ORDER BY protocolgroup DESC,
  totalbytes DESC
```

Comment: As you are telling that "you are trying to access a column from a nested SQL that is 2 levels down"..but when i replace 'not in' clause with 'in' clause..it works fine..so i don't think the problem is 2 level down query..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that B was redefined in the inner SQL.